# Error The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this Code:

```
    lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
    dataset=pd.read_csv('/titanic.csv')

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(6):
            if ((dataset.Age == j) & (dataset.Pclass == i)):
                dataset['Class']=lst[i*j]
```

I run it i got the Error in the title, I have tried every thing, i have tried `and` , `&`, and also `np.logical_and()` nothing seems to work.

But when i try to run the code alone without the loop as:

```
(dataset.Age == j) & (dataset.Pclass == i)
```

it run!

what is wrong with my code??

Comment: can you add what the `combine` variable is to the question as that will help people to be able to answer your question easier

Comment: yes, it was two data frames

Comment: that's a very vague answer can you be more specific? or better yet add an example to the question itself

Comment: i did, it was Titanic dataset i changed ages column using pd.cut() to get a ranges of ages, then for every range I gave a key.

Comment: the problem is related to nothing but to logical expression: if ((dataset.Age == j) & (dataset.Pclass == i))

Answer (score 1):

`dataset.Age == j` produces a `DataFrame`

`dataset.Pclass == i` produces a `DataFrame`

`DataFrame & DataFrame` produces a `DataFrame`

In Python, if you try to put a `np.array` or `DataFrame` into an `if`, it will complain, responding that it's unsure what you're trying to check (exactly the error you're getting).

What you're trying to do is to check if the resulting data frame is empty or not. I'd say, either wrap it in `len`, or use either [size](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) or [empty](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html).